# How to do multiple plane tracks from one video

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I haven't done any plane tracking before, but I'm thinking of making a video where I have a bunch of picture frames and I replace their images with a bunch of my blender work.  What is the process of doing more than one plane track in a video?  Are there plane track datablocks? (Again, I haven't really looked into this.)  Also, what is the best way to put them all together in the compositor?  Thanks!

Comment: start with these: https://vimeo.com/25516157 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXOnPisiugA the settings for motion tracking have changed a bit in recent versions, but the functionality and workflow is tha same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a plane track you select a minimum of four tracking points and then click Create Plane Track, which is available in the solve tab of the tools sidebar <kbd>T</kbd> in the Clip Editor.

I don't know if there are any limits, blender just lets you create as many plane tracks as you want for the current movie, I just created 40 as a test.

There is a plane track deform node that you can use in the compositor that will distort an image to match the plane track you choose.

[image]