# How do I overlay a photo of a face over a character on a video?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, tracking, masking

I downloaded an 80s cartoon intro (*Jem and the Holograms*; traditional cel animation) and I want to animate cutout photos of various family members' faces overtop the cartoon faces. Bonus points if I can apply some "worn out VHS tape" effect to the photo faces. Time permitting, I might even like to add some Terry Gilliam cutout jaw movement.

If I set up tracker points for the cartoon characters' eyes in the Movie Clip Editor, how do I get the photo face to follow these points, such that closely spaced markers indicate the photo face should be smaller/further away and vice versa, or approximate the head tilt like the popular "Elf Yourself" Christmas videos that were hot a few years ago? This seems doubly difficult since the cel animation has a lot of quick cuts and scene changes.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33203/how-to-do-multiple-plane-tracks-from-one-video

Comment: To do this using the compositor read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Track the element over which you want to overlay the image.

With the tracker selected got to the Solve tab and in the Geometry dropdown, click on **Link Empty to Track**.

[image]

That will create an empty that is parented to the camera and moves with the movement of the tracked element.

[image]

Add the picture of you want to overlay one using **Import Images as Planes**

[image]

Parent it to the empty: select the plane with the image and then while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> select also the empty and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>.

Now your image will move with the empty.

[image]

You might want to enable the video clip as background image at this point to see the have a reference of the movement.

[image]

[image]

For elements that change size or perspective you create a **Plane Track** tracking four points of the video. The instructions on how to do that are here:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.69/Motion_Tracker

and an excellent tutorial by Sebastian König [here](https://vimeo.com/25516157)

When you are done adding all the elements you want, you can render the scene using a node setup like this where you add your scene to the background video.

[image]

I'm just going to deal with the tracking part. The texturing should be a different post since it is a different question, and there is enough information  [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15784/repeat-a-generated-texture-in-cycles) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/transparent-lines-for-a-hologram-like-effect) on how to pull that off.

Comment: "Link Empty to Track" was the secret ingredient I needed, I think.

Is there any meaningful difference between using a movie clip node in the compositor as shown in your last screenshot versus using the Video Sequence Editor?

Comment: The compositor will give you access to other tools used by the Movie clip editor like masks, 2d stabilization and I find is more intuitive. But that might be just a personal choice...

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't have an "Import/Images as Planes" menu option. Not a big deal since I know how to add image textures to a shadeless material and stick it on a plane.

Comment: It's an addon. It shuld be enabled by default. If not you can enable it in the system preferences. It just saves you the hassle of creating a plane, scale it to the size of your image, UV unwrap and assigning the material...

Comment: Is there a way through constraints or drivers to automatically make the overlaid heads visible/invisible at the appropriate time based on the track marker it's following?

Comment: @amonroejj please ask that as a different question on a new post