# Tracking one strip, to another?

Tags: tracking, effects, fcurves

I've got one of my Video strips in the Video editor fully 3D-tracked by motion tracking. I wanted to add another video strip on top of it, following the track and being stabilized in the movie. How do I do this? I've been searching for 4 hours on how to do this...
[image: here's one]
[image: here's another]
I want to track the coin to the other movie. (I don't even know how to make it loop?)
I've tried fcurves, as the tracks are fcurves- I have no idea how to steal the fcurves from the track and paste it onto the transform effect strip.
Anyone know a solution? Currently, the coin is just static. I could 2d stabilize the shot, but then the coin would still be static- i want it to move according to the track.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to connect tracking information directly to the VSE. Trackers will not appear on the graph editor... but see if something like this, using the compositor, might work for you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/2d-elf-yourself-effect-animate-photo-of-faces-over-80s-cartoon-intro/36680#36680

Comment: yeah had to use the compositor. Still doesn't quite work, as the animated plane isn't being rendered above the video. i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: As Cegaton9 commented: I can not do it in the VSE. Fixed it in the Compositor and Instead used Animall to animate the coin on top of a plane.