# Overlaying an image to cover a face in a video?

Tags: edit-mode, video

I am trying to make a youtube video and in the part of the video I'm going to have a image of a face on top of my face to preserve my privacy. I tried going frame by frame with a picture that has a transparent background but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: Related: [How do I overlay a photo of a face over a character on a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36680/1853) and [How would I attach text to a tracked point on video clip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557)

Answer (score 21):

You can track a point in your footage and overlay an image in the compositor.

[image]

Common practice is to blur a face, when wanting to preserve the privacy of someone in a video. I will explain this first, as it is quicker to achieve.

[image]

#### Bluring a moving persons face in a video

1. Load the video into Blenders **Movie Clip Editor**. Set the scene start frame, end frame and resolution.
   [image: movie clip editor]
2. Go to the first frame of the scene. In the **Tools Tab** of the *Movie Clip Editor* in the Track section, set the *Tracking Settings* to **Previous Frame**. Click the **Add** button in the *Marker* section, then click on the video to add a marker. The marker should be positioned on the face you want to track. [Markers](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/clip/tools.html#marker-panel) can be translated, rotated and scaled. <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> 
   [image]
3. With the marker selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to track it.
4. Switch to [masking](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/masking.html) mode and add a new mask. 
   [image: movie clip editor]
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click to add new masking points. Add new masking points and track the face shape, which you want to mask. To close the mask, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Mask points can be selected, translated, rotated and scaled as usual.
   [image: create a mask]
6. Parent the mask points to the track by selecting the track and all the mask points and press the <kbd>Parent</kbd> button in the Tools menu.

   [Anonymously suggested: *Alternately, in case you are facing issues with track selection, click each of the mask points one after another while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> after each click. This will directly parent the mask points.*]

   [image]
7. The masked points will now follow the tracking marker. The mask can be keyframe at any frame by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. This may be necessary if the shape of the face changes. Mask *keyframes* can be viewed and edited in the **Dopesheet** in **Mask** mode. In the example, a key is used on the start and on the end frame. 
   [image]
8. In the node editor, go into **Compositing** mode and check **Use Nodes**. Add a Movie Clip node and load your clip.
   [image]
9. If the scene size and the source movie clip size are different, connect the *Image* output of the **Movie Clip** node to a **Scale** node set to *Render Size*. Connect the Scale nodes output to a Blur node. Set the amount of blurring you want in the X, Y fields. Add a **MixRGB** node and connect it to the Scale and the Blur node. Add a **Mask** node and select the mask. Connect it to the *Fac* input of the MixRGB node.
   [image]
10. Rendering the composite will blur the area, where the mask is.
    [image]

#### Overlaying an image onto a moving persons face in a video

Do steps 1 - 3 as explained above.

4. In the properties panel of the *Movie Clip Editor*, check **2D Stabilization**. Select the tracked marker and add it to the *Tracks for Location*.
    [image: tracking, stabilization 2D]
5. In compositor add an **Image** node and load the image, which you want to lay over the face. Add a **Transform** node to be able to position it later. Add a *Stabilize 2D* node and select the video which we used in the *Movie Clip Editor*. Check **Invert**. Since the Stabilization works in the space of the movie clip, we need to bring the smiley image into the Movie Clip space. To do this, add a **Set Alpha** node and connect it to the Movie Clip. Set the *Alpha* value to 0. Add an **Alpha Over** node and connect it to the **Set Alpha** and the **Transform** node. Append the **Stabilize 2D** node after the **Alpha Over**. After the stabilization the smiley image follow the track in the correct space. Add an **Alpha Over** node and connect it to the **Movie Clip** node and the **Stabilize 2D** node.
   [image: completed node setup]
6. Rendering this will overlay the smiley image ontop of the movie clip. The smiley image is matched moved with the stabilization node.
   [image]

Comment: How do you get from 6/7 to step 8?

Comment: This answer is amazing. I never would have figured out that I needed to get the coordinate space to be the same, let alone using a Set Alpha and Over Alpha to achieve it.