# Overlying images while tracking motion and adjusting angles

Tags: tracking

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like what is happening in the Gif's in the link below?

http://time.com/4655165/donald-trump-meme-gifs-executive-orders/

I've found a tutorial for 'flat' tracking here: [Overlaying an image to cover a face in a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video)

but I'm specifically looking to be able to adjust the angle of the image that is superimposed to match that of the video section it is tracking.

Thanks for your time as always.

Comment: use plane tracking see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902

Comment: Will this still work if some of the area being tracked has a part of the video footage move across it? What I mean is: if (like in the linked Gifs) a hand moves over the tracked area will the hand be visible and the inserted image beneath the hand?

Comment: Yes. Do a search for offset tracker.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28785/joining-2d-tracking-markers-with-an-offset

Comment: for elements that occlude the image you have to use masks