# Video editing/face replace

Tags: edit-mode, image, video

I'm new to Blender but want to edit video,I need to replace faces. I will cut face from picture and put there. Found this [Overlaying an image to cover a face in a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video) but don't get it. Can't found  2D Stabilization 
I need to replace and track faces in video.I'm beginner and need explanation step by step.I will cut face from picture and put on actor face in video. It's not that easy,video is long 4min It's fight scene from movie,they jumping ,spinning and I need to track all that.Don't even know how to add image :) I'm new to this and is all complicated :) If somebody can help me step by step I will really appreciate that.  And I hope that is clear now what I want to say.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add detailed information describing the steps you've taken so far.

Comment: Related: [How do I overlay a photo of a face over a character on a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36680/1853) and [How would I attach text to a tracked point on video clip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the "Motion Tracking" layout.
2. Load your video

[image]

3. Track high contrast points (ctrl+LMB to create a tracking point, then press the track forward/backward buttons)

[image]

4. Change the layout to "Video Editing"
5. Drag in your tracked footage
6. Drag in your image file
7. Use the [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) addon to position and size your image over the face

   - Alt+S will rescale an image to it's original aspect ratio FYI
8. Use the "Transform from 2D Track" function (also part of the VSE_Transform_Tools addon) to pin the image to the face.

[image]

Comment: I need explanation step by step :) It's not that easy,video is long 4min
It's fight scene from movie,they jumping ,spinning and I need to track all that. Don't have motion tracking option up there.I can put trackers in movie clip editor. When I press Ctrl+T is very slow then I need to move green bar with mouse. And through the whole video I need to move that tracking square to the face.Don't even know how to add image :) I'm new to this and is all complicated :)

Comment: I will tell you what I know and how I do that. I go to movie clip editor then open video after that turn on AV-sync,adjust Start and End and frame rate. Then go to Tracking settings and change keyframe to previous frame then add marker. I put markers where I want and after that don't now what to do :(