# How do I animate an image in the Video Sequence Editor to match the underlying video?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm new to the program. In the video editor, is there an easy way to move an added image smoothly in one direction that it will be synchronous with the base video?

I tried splitting the image into many little pieces but it should be easier than that.

EDIT: So I want the picture follow the original movement and stay like a mask.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some illustration of what you're looking for? (`Edit` link then use the `add image` icon

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "synchronous with the base video". Also, please make the title specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno If you type "[ edit ]" (without any spaces) it will autoformat it to link to the edit button, like this [edit].

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is quite easy to do in blender with motion tracking.

Open a new project as VFX File > New > VFX

In the Clip Editor (not the Video Sequence Editor) open the video you want to use.

[image]

Add a tracker on the face or whatever feature you want to track.

Track the element.

[image]

In the solve tab of the tools window, in the geometry section use "Link empty to track".

And in the scene setup select "Set as Background" so that you can see the image as background on the camera view.

Import the image as plane, set it where you need.

You can then use that empty as parent to any object on the 3d workspace.

[image]

[image]

To render, composite the rendered image on top of the movie clip (the image used in the 3D viewport is for reference only).

[image]

[image]

Or you can opt to create 4 trackers and creata a "Plane Track" that can be used to deform an image as if follows the placement of the trackers.

Read:

[How would I attach text to a tracked point on video clip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557)

[Is it possible to take a mask clip and 'connect' it to a specific point on a moving object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902)

[Overlaying an image to cover a face in a video?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video/65017#65017)

Comment: Made my day! Nice to have you back :P

Answer (score 1):

The Video editor in Blender is a very old part. I think it would be easier if you add the image as an object in blender

(add image as plane: see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mc8Ws9Ngjx8 )

and then move the image or move the camera, very nice.
You could even let it drop a shadow and use a background behind it, it would look like you are filming a photograph. 
This is a little more complicated than using the video editor, but is also a lot more flexible.
You could for example use the physical engine and kinda "throw" the picture and let it land on the floor and have several images do that, like throwing down photographs.

Comment: This can be automated using tracking.