# How do I render my nodes on this video?

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor

I attempted to overlay a person's face with a mask I set up my composite nodes, but it just will not render it at all

If you could help me out that would be so appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174215/how-do-i-animate-an-image-in-the-video-sequence-editor-to-match-the-underlying-v/188346#188346

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/how-to-have-person-in-video-mask-added-geometry-as-they-walk-in-front/183108#183108

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65007/overlaying-an-image-to-cover-a-face-in-a-video

Comment: @susu hi Susu, i used that exact guide to make it but it still does not work :(