# Couldn't render a movie clip with a moving image in a composition layer

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I couldn't render a movie clip with a tracked object on it.
I added **Movie Clip** and **Render layers** as inputs and **Alpha Over** as a node to combine images. But when pressing CTRL+F12 it seems like I see only **Render layers** in a view pane, no image from movie clip.
What could be the nature of the problem? I've tried disabling **Sequencer** in **Post processing** section of **Output properties**.

Here is a short video of the problem: https://i.imgur.com/eesgWvW.mp4

Any suggestions would be very helpful for me.
I used https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188346/2980 as a guide.

I'm using Eevee render engine.

[image: composition]

Comment: Does the Render Layer have a transparent background? It looks all grey, a transparent background is indicated by a checkerboard texture... have you enabled _Render Properties_ > _Film_ > _Transparent_? If not, the _Alpha Over_ node will not work because there is no transparency in your render where the movie clip can be seen through.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann that's the solution, much obliged! How could I accept your answer?

Comment: Wait for my answer to be posted ;) Comments cannot be accepted. But there it is, now you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendered image has no transparent background as you can see by the grey color. If it were transparent, this would be indicated by a checkerboard and your *Render Layers* node should look like this:

[image: transparent layer]

To use the *Alpha Over* node, the background of the overlaying image has to be transparent in order for the underlying movie clip to be visible. To change it, go to *Render Properties* > *Film* and enable the *Transparent* option:

[image: film transparent]