# Translate track marker 2d position to empty in 3d space

Tags: video, constraints, tracking

[image: Example]

How do you transform a track marker to a empty in 3d space?

I only need the 2d position relative to the camera's view.

Comment: For a 3D track you need at least 8 markers to do a camera solve... Watch the wonderful tutorial "Track, Match, Blend" from Sebastian König.

Comment: That's just the thing I don't want/need a camera solve. Just a empty in 3d space to be in the same position as the track marker when viewed from camera view...

Comment: [Track, Match, Blend - 02 One Point Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3E3zRQSpcI)... It's not possible to use a 3D empty with only 2D coordinates and a camera view.

Comment: Well I couldn't have misunderstood your comment more. Thanks.

Comment: related, possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-do-i-overlay-a-photo-of-a-face-over-a-character-on-a-video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Solution]
For the one who didn't see the video in comments:

Reconstruction > link empty to track