# Use tracking point to move a plane with an image on it,

Tags: tracking

I'm looking to track an object within a strip of frames in the video editor.

To clarify, I'm not trying to track an object and solve the camera motion. I'm looking to use a single tracking point to track the head of a character from a video and i would like to make a plane with an image on it follow that point.

Comment: watch for "Track, Match, Blend!" on YouTube...

Comment: The BF tutorial for that is called [Track Match Blend](https://cloud.blender.org/p/track-match-blend/) - you can find copies on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=track+match+blend).

Comment: I'm unlcear on the question, but as far as I know there is no way to bring the tracking information into the VSE. Tracking is done in the Movie Clip Edtior and the tracker information can be used on the Compositor, from there you would need to render the result and import that into the VSE.

Comment: I should have clarified when i made the post, i'm not looking to place objects into a video clip like one would usually use the tracking for, I'm looking to do something along the lines of tracking a persons head for example and layering another picture over the video.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38557/1853 - Read the las section of the answer to use the compositor only http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-do-i-overlay-a-photo-of-a-face-over-a-character-on-a-video

Comment: Use a plane track: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902

Comment: Thank you cegaton, this is exactly what i was looking for.