# How to add a 2D png into my tracking data instead of using a 3D model

Tags: tracking

I have a GIF I'm working on where I track a 2-D PNG of Nero's head onto tracking data. Trouble is, every tutorial I go to uses a 3-D model (like the monkey) to link to the tracker and none uses a 2-D image. Is it possible?

Comment: relted: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36674/how-do-i-overlay-a-photo-of-a-face-over-a-character-on-a-video/36680#36680 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557

Comment: @cegaton my version of Blender doesn't have that option: https://imgur.com/a/DuqzKme

Comment: Just enable the images as plane addon.