# Overlay Another Video in the Blender Video Editor but at an Angle

Tags: texturing, uv, video-sequence-editor, video

I am trying to overlay another video on top of my animation in the Blender video editor to it look like the overlaid video is playing on a tv. The problem I have is that the TV is at an angle and it won't line up well by just rotating it. How can I get my video to appear at an angle to fit the TV through the Blender Video Editor? Also, the animation I made will be looping while the much longer overlaid video will be playing so putting the video into the actual animation won't work. Below is the TV in my animation, I appreciate if anyone can help me!

[image]

Comment: You should feel confident that this is a well known and well solved problem that you can also demonstrate with some research.   You may also investigate a Blender feature ... approximately named Planes as Images.

Comment: Please show your mesh for the  TV and the UV Map which places images or video on the TV Screen.   Please see a tutorial on the either here at BSE or the famous video website which has a  name that rhymes with noonoob.  Any image can be placed on a rectangle or parallelogram et cetera .  Tutorials will show you this.  If you do not know what a UV Map is for  then seek out a tutorial that already exists here or on the site mentioned above.  Blender screen captures, provided by you, will allow people to help you only on the fine points rather than a tutorial.

Comment: Is it for rendering with Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: If you have the 3D models, then use the video as material texture for the screen. If you have the video only, you can use a plane track. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33203/how-to-do-multiple-plane-tracks-from-one-video and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183012/how-can-i-track-a-moving-board-and-superimpose-a-video-on-top-of-it